# Error when executing headless firefox through Selenium

Tags: ubuntu, x11, firefox, headless, selenium

I am trying to execute headless firefox on the remote machine(running Ubuntu 16.04) through Selenium via SSH. However, this gives me a "Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays" error. My host machine runs Windows. I do not want to see the graphical output. It is just being used for selenium testing.

I am using X Virtual Frame Buffer to act as a dummy driver:

```
Xvfb :10 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
```

I also have exported the DISPLAY environment variable with the value of 10 for this specific case.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: When I simply run "sudo firefox" in my commandline over SSH after running xvbf, no errors are thrown. Errors are only thrown when running firefox through selenium.

**More Details:-**

I am calling firefox through selenium. The exact error that the selenium standalone server gives is:-

```
17:52:55.218 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities     [{browserName=firefox, platform=ANY,     firefox_profile=UEsDBBQAAAAAAJuOD0nf9RXUMgAAA...}]])
17:52:55.230 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities   [{browserName=firefox, platform=ANY, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQAAAAAAJuOD0nf9RXUMgAAA...}]
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host     127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays
```

Comment: Apparently [ubuntu does not come with `xinit` installed by default](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762782/linux-without-graphical-os-but-with-graphical-resources) so, maybe, firefox cannot find that it should be using xorg as the backend.

Comment: @grochmal I do not really know xserver in depth. Can you please explain why I need xinit?

Comment: It is just because of the variable `GDK_BACKEND`, the only place I know that that is used is in [forcing GTK to use `wayland`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wayland#GUI_libraries).  In that case it would be set to `GDK_BACKEND=wayland`.  The equivalent for xorg would be `GDK_BACKEND=xinit` (but that is a guess).

Comment: Apparently this is caused because of incompatibility between Firefox 48 and Selenium(selenium extension is not signed in firefox 48, and firefox 48 only runs signed extensions). I just went ahead with using chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is caused because of incompatibility between Firefox 48 and Selenium(selenium extension is not signed in firefox 48, and firefox 48 only runs signed extensions). I just used chrome, as my use-case was not extremely browser-specific.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue with Firefox.
The steps are:

1. Downgraded Firefox from 49.0 to 46.0
2. Install XVFB by command `sudo apt-get install xvfb`
3. Run Selenium with the command `xvfb-run java8 -jar selenium-project.jar`

My Selenium version is `2.53.1` and Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `DISPLAY` env variable method didn't work, but I switched to using `xvfb-run <command>` (in my case `xvfb-run npm test`) and it worked great! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have answered here 
           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250580/error-gdk-backend-does-
not-match-available-displays-running-selenium-using-cro